# Timeout after launching IE using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to execute the code below. After launching the provided URL on the IE browser, the next line of code times out and does not get executed.
Please help!

Apps and version:
  Selenium: 3.141
  Python: 3.8
  Pycharm IDE: 2020.1

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Ie(executable_path="...\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://google.co.in")   # Launch is successful.

print(7+7)    # This is not executed. The process times out.
```

Comment: try adding "import time" and then "time.sleep(5)" before the line print(7+7) and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to proceed now.
I was using 64bit IE-driver, I tried with 32-bit now which is allowing me to proceed after browser launch.
No time-out observed.

Thanks